# In clojure how can defmacro be defined in terms of itself?

Tags: clojure

I have been looking at the source for defmacro which uses "let" in its definition:

```
(def

 ^{:doc "Like defn, but the resulting function name is declared as a
  macro and will be used as a macro by the compiler when it is
  called."
   :arglists '([name doc-string? attr-map? [params*] body]
                 [name doc-string? attr-map? ([params*] body)+ attr-map?])
   :added "1.0"}
 defmacro (fn [&form &env 
                name & args]
             (let [prefix (loop [p (list name) args args]
```

However, "let" is defined as a macro itself:

```
(defmacro let
  "binding => binding-form init-expr

  Evaluates the exprs in a lexical context in which the symbols in
  the binding-forms are bound to their respective init-exprs or parts
  therein."
  {:added "1.0", :special-form true, :forms '[(let [bindings*] exprs*)]}
  [bindings & body]
  (assert-args
     (vector? bindings) "a vector for its binding"
     (even? (count bindings)) "an even number of forms in binding vector")
  `(let* ~(destructure bindings) ~@body))
```

Can someone explain how this works as I can't understand how "defmacro" can be defined in terms of things which need "defmacro" to already be defined. (if that makes sense :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

recusrive macros work fine and occur in many place in both the clojure language core and in other programs. **macros are just functions that return S-Expressions**, so they can be recursive just as functions can. In the case of `let` in your example it's actually caling `let*` which is a different function (its fine to have * in a functions name), so although recursive macros are fine, this doesn't happen to be an example of them

Comment: Isn't the question about the apparent circular definition?

Answer (score 8):

This is possible because before defining `defmacro` function in core.clj there is already a definition of `let` at [this location](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L32) (which gets redefined later). Macros are just normal functions and the var they are bound to has meta data key `:macro` with value `true` so that at compile time the compiler can differentiate between a macro (which execute at compile time) with a function, without this meta key there is no way to differentiate between a macro and a function because macro itself is a function that happens to process S-expressions.

Comment: Nope: `(fn* let [&form &env & decl] (cons 'let* decl))`.. where does it depends on let? It is defining let function. It uses let* which is already defined in the java code of clojure